# unix command to perform list comparisons equivalent to a set operation

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line

What unix command/utility can I use to create my final list of names based on my 2 lists below? This would be like doing a `SET` operation. However, the main comparison has to be against `NameList1`. If `NameList2` has an extra name(s), don't include it in the master list.

Note: I cannot have it sorted (alphabetical, etc). I need to preserve the column position (natural order) as I've already provided in my list top, down. Thanks for your help.

NameList1:

```
Joe
John
Mary
Mike
Allan
David
Andrew
Matt
```

NameList2:

```
Joe
John
Mary
George
Jeff
Allan
David
Andrew
Frank
```

If I do a `diff` with a side-by-side compare you can see the comparison. Like so:

```
-bash-4.1$ diff --side-by-side NameList1.txt NameList2.txt
Joe                             Joe
John                                John
Mary                                Mary
Mike                                  | George
                                  > Jeff
Allan                               Allan
David                               David
Andrew                              Andrew
Matt                                  | Frank
```

The outcome, expected  for my final list would be:

```
Joe
John
Mary
Mike
Allan
David
Andrew
Matt
```

Where `George, Jeff, Frank` is removed from NameList1. How can I product this final list? Is there a better tool command? Am I using `diff` correctly?

Comment: is the outcome identical with your list1?

Comment: Your problem is not well defined.

Comment: As listed in my `master` list is what I need to produce. So in otherwords whatever is in NameList2 that is not in NameList1, remove it from NameList1.

Comment: @HansThen - i tried to clarify my question. Hope that makes better sense. Thanks.

Comment: `cat NameList1` should do the trick.

Comment: You say "whatever is in NameList2 that is not in NameList1, remove it from NameList1" - but those lines *already aren't* in NameList1 and your result will always be equal to NameList1.

Comment: @BenjaminW. - ah, yes. I misspoke. WIll edit that response.

Comment: @noober - on a second thought you don't seem to care for what is there in second file, so Hans Then's comment is very relevant in this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using a simple `join` command.
In my Mac, following gives expected result

`join -a1 NameList1 NameList2`

```
>      -a file_number
>                  In addition to the default output, produce a line for each
>                  unpairable line in file file_number.
```

**Edit**

On Linux, `--no-checkorder` option would avoid checking sorted order on inputs.

`join -a1 --nocheck-order NameList1 NameList2`

Comment: This works, however is there a way to surpress the output `join: file 2 is not in sort order`, `join: file1 is not in sorted order`?

Comment: I don't get this message in Mac. May be there is a switch to suppress warnings? have a look at `man join`

Comment: ah..you are right on a mac it works. however, i'm running centOS 6 and i don't see on man pages to surpress that.